# Convert bash script to python

Tags: python, bash

I have a bash script and i want to convert it to python.

This is the script :

```
mv $1/positive/*.$3 $2/JPEGImages
mv $1/negative/*.$3 $2/JPEGImages
mv $1/positive/annotations/*.xml $2/Annotations
mv $1/negative/annotations/*.xml $2/Annotations
cut -d' ' -f1 $1/positive_label.txt > $4_trainval.txt
```

My problem is : i didn't found how to past positive_label.txt in $4_trainval.txt.

This is my try, it's the first time i work with python. please help me to make it work.
thank you.

```
import sys # Required for reading command line arguments
import os # Required for path manipulations
from os.path import expanduser # Required for expanding '~', which stands for home folder. Used just in case the command line arguments contain "~". Without this, python won't parse "~"
import glob
import shutil


def copy_dataset(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4):
    path1 = os.path.expanduser(arg1)
    path2 = os.path.expanduser(arg2) # 
    frame_ext = arg3 # File extension of the patches  
    pos_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path1,'positive/'+'*.'+frame_ext))
    neg_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path1,'negative/'+'*.'+frame_ext))
    pos_annotation = glob.glob(os.path.join(path1,'positive/annotations/'+'*.'+xml))
    neg_annotation = glob.glob(os.path.join(path1,'negative/annotations/'+'*.'+xml))

    #mv $1/positive/*.$3 $2/JPEGImages
    for x in pos_files:
        shutil.copyfile(x, os.path.join(path2,'JPEGImages'))

    #mv $1/negative/*.$3 $2/JPEGImages
    for y in neg_files:
        shutil.copyfile(y, os.path.join(path2,'JPEGImages'))

    #mv $1/positive/annotations/*.xml $2/Annotations
    for w in pos_annotation:
        shutil.copyfile(w, os.path.join(path2,'Annotations'))

    #mv $1/negative/annotations/*.xml $2/Annotations
    for z in neg_annotation:
        shutil.copyfile(z, os.path.join(path2,'Annotations'))

    #cut -d' ' -f1 $1/positive_label.txt > $4_trainval.txt
    for line in open(path1+'/positive_label.txt')
        line.split(' ')[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without testing, something like that should works.

```
#cut -d' ' -f1 $1/positive_label.txt > $4_trainval.txt
positive = path1+'/positive_label.txt'
path4 = os.path.join(arg4, '_trainval.txt')

with open(positive, 'r') as input_, open(path4, 'w') as output_:
    for line in input_.readlines():
        output_.write(line.split()[0] + "\n")
```

This code defines the two files we will work with and opens both. The first is opened in read mode, the second in write mode. For each line in the *input* file, we write the first find data separated by a space to the *output* file.

Check [Reading and Writing Files in Python](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python) for more informations about files into Python.